# Manually create and validate a JWT token

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 [Tools](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/tools.html) to manually create a token:

```
var token = await _tools.IssueClientJwtAsync(
   clientId: "client_id",
   lifetime: lifetimeInSeconds,
   audiences: new[] { TokenHelper.Audience },
   additionalClaims:new [] { new Claim("some_id", "1234") }
);
```

I wonder if there is a way (***using what IdentityServer4 already have***) to manually decode and validate the token.

To decode the token right now I'm using JwtSecurityTokenHandler (System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt):

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var tokenDecoded = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
```

It is quite simple so I'm happy to keep this if IdentityServer4 doesn't have an equivalent.

What is more important is the ***validation*** of the token. I found and adapt [this example](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-dotnet-validate-jwt/blob/master/IdentityModel-RS256/Program.cs) that does the job. Here the code from Github:

```
const string auth0Domain = "https://jerrie.auth0.com/"; // Your Auth0 domain
const string auth0Audience = "https://rs256.test.api"; // Your API Identifier
const string testToken = ""; // Obtain a JWT to validate and put it in here

   // Download the OIDC configuration which contains the JWKS
   // NB!!: Downloading this takes time, so do not do it very time you need to validate a token, Try and do it only once in the lifetime
   //  of your application!!
IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"{auth0Domain}.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () => await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None));

// Configure the TokenValidationParameters. Assign the SigningKeys which were downloaded from Auth0. 
// Also set the Issuer and Audience(s) to validate
TokenValidationParameters validationParameters =
    new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = auth0Domain,
        ValidAudiences = new[] { auth0Audience },
        IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys
    };

// Now validate the token. If the token is not valid for any reason, an exception will be thrown by the method
SecurityToken validatedToken;
JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var user = handler.ValidateToken(testToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

// The ValidateToken method above will return a ClaimsPrincipal. Get the user ID from the NameIdentifier claim
// (The sub claim from the JWT will be translated to the NameIdentifier claim)
Console.WriteLine($"Token is validated. User Id {user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value}");
```

The code above is doing the job. I just wonder if IdentityServer4 has already something "simpler" that just does the token validation as the code above does.

Comment: can you explain why you need to manually validate the token? Are you using IDS4 or just the tools?

Comment: We are using the full IDS4. But in this case we want to send a link with the token via SMS to user (we know the phone via a 3rd party integration, so we are 99% sure the phone belong to the user). Once the user click on the link he goes to our portal, that will call IDS4 to check the token and immediately exchange it for a new one (it will be transparent to the user). User will have minimal claim, it will see just one page with minimal info. For any other link in the page he will need to do the full login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called token delegation,
you can implement it using `Extension Grants` on IDS. Here is sample code from [docs](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/topics/extension_grants.html?highlight=iextensiongrantvalidator#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant)

```
public class DelegationGrantValidator : IExtensionGrantValidator
{
    private readonly ITokenValidator _validator;

    public DelegationGrantValidator(ITokenValidator validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public string GrantType => "delegation";

    public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
    {
        var userToken = context.Request.Raw.Get("token");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userToken))
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
            return;
        }

        var result = await _validator.ValidateAccessTokenAsync(userToken);
        if (result.IsError)
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
            return;
        }

        // get user's identity
        var sub = result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;
        
        //Generate a new token manually if needed 
        //Call another API is needed 

        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(sub, GrantType);
        return;
    }
}
```

Token validation is done using `ITokenValidator` in above code, you can use this validator in manual validation as well.

[Here](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/10/self-issuing-an-identityserver4-token-in-an-identityserver4-service/) is another example.